# Как создавать контрастные по отношению друг к другу цвета?

Tags: алгоритм, цвета

В моем проекте есть возможность рисовать график по некоторым наборам данных. Их количество варьируется от 1 до... до тех пор, пока пользователю не надоест добавлять новые наборы данных.

Необходимо, чтобы на графике были хорошо различимы ВСЕ линии. Для этого, нужно чтобы все линии были более-менее контрастны по отношению к друг-другу, на сколько я понимаю.

Вопрос - как создавать эти контрастные цвета?

Comment: Вот тут вариант с 10 цветами: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46463

Comment: @Kromster, круто, спасибо! А как быть, если наборов данных может понадобиться больше 10?

Comment: что-то вроде 50 + random(100) для каждого из rgb

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, ну по идее, при использовании чистого рандома, все равно могут появится очень похожие цвета.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev плохой вариант, т.к. большинство цветов будет просто серо-буро-малиновыми.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов Больше 10 уже сложно, смотрите карту метро Москвы и других крупных городов.

Comment: тут надо играться, у меня получалось давно попадать в сок очень хорошо

Comment: @Kromster, да, видимо больше 10 взаимо-контрастных цветов нельзя получить =(

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev в любом случае, рандом лучше делать в HSB, а не RGB

Comment: @ИльяБизунов добавляйте пунктиры, обводку, узоры )

Comment: @Kromster, да, я тоже думал об этом варианте =)

Comment: Илья, вам уже правильно посоветовали отталкиваться от модели HSB. Берёте для каждого варианта максимальную насыщенность, на круге цветового тона выбираете несколько точек на равном удалении друг от друга. Если цветов нужно больше шести-семи, то можно брать одну точку для двух-трёх цветов - а варьировать только яркость. Какие именно значения яркости брать - отчасти зависит от фона, тут нужно просто посмотреть и подобрать два-три значения. Ну а потом всё это дело тупо переводите в RGB, формулы можно нагуглить.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов, если вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос, пожалуйста, опубликуйте ответ

Comment: @4per, а на StackOverflow можно как-то "пометить" комментарий, если я считаю, что он отвечает на заданный вопрос? Или только копировать текст и постить ответ?

Comment: На сколько я знаю, такой возможности нет. Можно попросить автора комментария оформить ответ, или описать как именно вы решили проблему.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [“Best” series of colors to use for differentiating series in publication-quality plots](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/118033/2530) (обратите внимание на цвета в рисунке в самом [популярном ответе](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/118042/2530)—это не ошибка)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По совету @Kromster'a воспользовался вот этим [скриптом](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46463):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    colors[i] = HSV(0.1 * i, 0.5, 1.0);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Kromster, обновил ответ.